# mupdf not building in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, mupdf

Not able to build mupdf. I am getting the following error:
Generating cmap and font files
Apple broke Xcode external targets yet again, and I can't be bothered to fix it.
Run the 'make generate' command manually from now on!
If you see an error while running GEN, you've forgotten.
Building libraries for i386.
    GEN generated/cmap_cns.h
/bin/sh: ./build/debug-ios-i386/cmapdump: No such file or directory
make: *** [generated/cmap_cns.h] Error 127

Comment: And did you what the error message suggests?

Comment: Yes and the make generate runs fine. But when I open the project file in xcode I still get the error "/bin/sh: ./build/debug-ios-i386/cmapdump: No such file or directory" as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Do what the error message tells you to do.

Open a terminal, cd to the mupdf directory, and run "make generate".

Comment: Yes and the make generate runs fine. But when I open the project file in xcode I still get the error "/bin/sh: ./build/debug-ios-i386/cmapdump: No such file or directory" as mentioned above.

Comment: I will pay 20$ to the paypal account of the person who figures out this before I do.

Comment: Are you sure the "make generate" runs fine? If you have "generated/*.h" files, the build/debug-ios-i326/cmapdump command shouldn't be invoked, so make sure the "generated" directory has been populated with both cmap_*.h and font_*.h files. I just did a clean checkout and build as per the instructions and all works fine.

Comment: These are the list of files in the generated directory.
cmap_cns.h cmap_gb.h cmap_japan.h cmap_korea.h font_base14.h font_cjk.h font_cjk_full.h font_droid.h js_util.h

Also note that I get the error I reported, when I open the project file for mupdf in xcode

Comment: That list of file looks good. I have no idea what could be going wrong then. Apple likes to break things every release, so I would make sure you use both the latest git checkout of mupdf and Xcode 4.6 as that's all I can test, and that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem.After "make generate", I restarted Xcode, then build successfully.

Comment: I got this after I "make generate" and run the project in Xcode "/bin/sh: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ar: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to generate the MuPDF library without using any `make generate` or shell script. 
I wrote a small step-by-step tutorial on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324014/develop-an-ebook-reader-on-iphone-ipad-using-mupdf-library/31111924#31111924).

Cheers