# Integrate MuPDF Swift - IOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pdf, mupdf

After I created a `Objective-c` class in my project based on [JosephH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/292166/josephh) [example](https://github.com/jogu/MuPDF-example). I imported it in my bridging header file.
I was actually able to make it work using a .pdf file in the main bundle

`NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hello-world" ofType:@"pdf"];`.

which returns:

> "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/63F34E6B-75A7-4CC0-9149-9DF2861DF3A2/sempre-editora.app/hello-world.pdf"

It did render everything all right, zooming and everything. but when I try to render a file in my "Documents" folder it just doesn't work. I even tried to just put this "hello-world.pdf" file inside my "Documents" to try it out and it still doesn't work.
This is the path of my documents file:

> "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AF776E50-FAAC-4274-824F-4F9634E072F6/Documents/70-10"

What could be the problem? I'm sure this is the correct path for my file, and it actually exists, the framework doesn't throw any error but I just get a gray background.

I thought it could be because my file doesn't have an extension but when I add a .pdf to my file and try to render it, it crashes.

[image: Screen Example]

After some tests I realised that when the PDF has two pages, and I go to the second page, it actually renders the pdf.

Comment: I wonder if the crash when you add the .pdf is a clue - whereabouts is it crashing? Does the *same* PDF file display okay in the example?

Comment: It crashes when I initialize my MuDocumentController, it says "Cannot load document".  When I try to render from a file inside my project and presentViewController it renders fine. When I try start a pageViewController with it (same file inside my project), it doesn't render, only when I pass page

Comment: I think there's probably several different things going on here. To get to the bottom of it we need to apply a systematic approach and start from a simple point that should work, then make one change at a time till it doesn't work, and then diagnose why that change didn't work. If you do exactly what https://github.com/jogu/MuPDF-example/blob/master/MuPDF-example/AppDelegate.m what is the **first** thing that goes wrong and what is the exact error message? (I cannot find the error you mention, "Cannot load document", anywhere in the code.)

Comment: Basically if I try to display using "self.presentViewController" it renders normally... If I try to display it using a page View Controller it doesn't render ... No errors, or anything... but if the pdf has two pages or more and I go to the second page, it renders...