# Unable to convert mupdf into static library on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, mupdf

I am trying to convert mupdf (latest source) to a static library. I cloned the source and am able to run it on my iPad. However I am unable to compile it into a static library. I followed the instructions in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012554-CH2-SW1 to create a static library but I am unable to generate the library (I am assuming there is some complex linking that needs to be done that I am unaware of). Since I am new to iOS development could someone direct me on how to go about it? My objective is to tweak the mupdf code, add the shared library to my app and call classes in the mupdf source from my app (ex: Call the View Controller MuDocumentController from my app).

Thanks

Comment: did u find a way to incorporate it?

Comment: did u find a way to incorporate it?

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a small [step-by-step tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324014/develop-an-ebook-reader-on-iphone-ipad-using-mupdf-library/31111924#31111924) to generate and integrate the MuPDF library into a Xcode project.

I hope it will help you !

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to use the [MuPDF CocoaPod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/MuPDF). There is an [example application based on that pod](https://github.com/jogu/MuPDF-example).

Even if you don't want to use the CocoaPod, running `pod install` is likely the simplest way to generate the necessary fat .a files.

Comment: I tried to run pod install but it gives CODE_SIGNING_IDENTITY error.  Do you have any idea about this? I have raise a new question on this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64552031/pod-install-fails-when-installing-mupdf