# Pod Install fails when installing MuPDF

Tags: objective-c, swift, iphone, cocoapods, mupdf

I'm developing a pdf viewer app and I'm using MuPdf library cocoapods. I created a new project, added a pod file and ran pod install. Following error occurred. Any help is appreciated to fix this. I have set automatically manage signing in the project.

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing MuPDF (1.10)
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
cd platform/ios
# release armv7 + arm64
xcodebuild -scheme MuPDF -configuration Release CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO

# debug 64bit sim
xcodebuild -scheme MuPDF -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
cd ../../build/
for i in mupdf mupdfthird; do
    LIB=lib${i}.a
    lipo -create -output $LIB release-ios-i386-x86_64/$LIB release-ios-armv7-arm64/$LIB
done

# rename to avoid any conflict with the libmupdf.a that the pod generates
mv libmupdf.a libmupdfcore.a

# copy iOS headers into the general include directory, as
# cocoapods 1.0 insists that all headers are under the
# header_mappings_dir location
cd ..
cp platform/ios/Classes/*.h platform/ios/common.h include/mupdf/
cd platform/ios
# now fix the imports/includes to be mupdf/foo.h instead of foo.h
find . -name '*.[mh]' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -pi -e 's,#import "Mu,#import "mupdf/Mu,'
find . -name '*.[mh]' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -pi -e 's,#include "common.h",#include       "mupdf/common.h",'
find . -name '*.[mh]' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -pi -e 's,#import "common.h",#import "mupdf/common.h",'

# the reference to memory.h in memento.h upsets xcode when
# building a module (fixed upstream for version after 1.9)
cd ../..
find . -name 'memento.h' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -pi -e 's,#include <memory.h>,#include    <stdlib.h>,'

Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -scheme MuPDF -configuration Release CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO

Build settings from command line:
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = 
    CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED = NO

note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
error: An empty identity is not valid when signing a binary for the product type 'Application'. (in target 'MuPDF' from project 'MuPDF')

** BUILD FAILED **
```

Comment: Seems there is a problem with your credentials. I think you are adding it as a binary and thus it needs to be signed. I think, in this new project of yours, just be sure your credentials there are in order and I hope it will fix it, but, looking at the output, maybe you need to tweak some settings somewhere else as well.

Comment: pod try MuPDF gives the same error.